# Hibernate named query re-parsed

Tags: oracle, hibernate, jdbc, prepared-statement

We are using hibernate named query as follows :

```
named_query :   Select this_  from  TableA this_  where this_.id  in( select max(id) from TableA where COLA is null group by COLB ) and rownum=1  
Query query = getNamedQuery("nq.select.DirtySubject.onMaxDirtySubjectRecId");
List<SomeObject>  objectList       = query.list();
```

The query has been flagged by the DBAs and the comments verbatim are as follows

> These indicate the SQL statements that are consuming the most parsing
>   resources every time they execute.
>   The SQL statements that appear in
>   this report are probably being reparsed. Excessively-parsed SQL
>   statements should be optimized to reduce their parsing frequency. This
>   involves using bind variables and identical statement syntax and case,
>   in order to be able to reuse any previously-parsed statements in the
>   SQL cache.
>   Examine these queries to see if any SQL optimization is
>   possible and reasonable.

**Other material facts:**
This query is part of a polling logic and gets fired repeatedly.
Database:Oracle 11G
Technology stack : Java,Hibernate,Tomcat,Linux,Oracle 11G

**Questions:**
1: Behind the scene- Hibernate will be using Prepared statement - correct ?
2: What can we possibly do more from the application side - to avoid re-parsing of this query ?
3: Anything we can do on the Database server to avoid re-parsing ?

Answer (score 0):

The comment talks about *parsing resources* (in contrast to *execution time/resources*), but the statement itself does not really look that difficult to parse. The most interesting information would be the execution plan. I assume that the query is always the same (but the comment contains the word "probably").

As for question 1:

If you want to make sure that prepared statements do help, you can try to run the same query without Hibernate - just plain java.sql, PreparedStatement.

If so, there is a Hibernate prepared statement cache, but I have never used it.

As for question 2:

If this is your hotspot, you can use "direct SQL" with Hibernate (if it and your connection pool allows the caching of prepared statements) or even without it: Then you have full control.

As for question 3: Have a look on Oracle 11g result cache.